# How can we save an avro file with a json schema using RHadoop (rmr2)?

Tags: r, avro, rhadoop

The sample implementation of avro output format using make.output.format uses "bytes" as schema. Instead I want to specify a json schema to the avro file. I could not find how we can do this. I guess there would be some backend.parameters which will define this.

```
avro.output.format =
  function(kv, con)
    writeLines(
      unlist(
        rmr2:::reduce.keyval(
          kv,
          function(k, v)
            paste(
              toJSON(k, .escapeEscapes = TRUE),
              toJSON(v, .escapeEscapes = TRUE),
              sep = "\t"))),
      con = con)

avroOF =
  make.output.format(
    format = avro.output.format,
    mode = "text",
    streaming.format = "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroTextOutputFormat",
    backend.parameters =
      list(
        hadoop =
          list(
            libjars = avro.jar)))
```

Comment: No, the capability you need is missing from the AvroTextOutputFormat class. You need to write some Java and a new output format to do what you need.